# php function variable in other function

Tags: php, function, variables

```
function drop_2($drop_var2)
{

...

}

function drop_3($drop_var3)
{

...

}


function drop_4($drop_var4)
{

...

}
```

How can i use $drop_var2 in drop_3 function? + $drop_var2 and $drop_var3 in drop_4 function?

Comment: Pass them as a parameter?  Within `drop_2`, call `drop_3($drop_var2)`.

Comment: $drop_var2, $drop_var3, $drop_var4 are all parameters for their respective functions. When you call the function, you use a variable as the parameter, that variable you can use it for all functions...

Comment: Why do you want to? Trying to use a variable from another function is generally a sign that your code is structured wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a global variables

```
function drop_4($drop_var4)
{
   global  $drop_var2,$drop_3;
...

}
```

Comment: Even though it's possible to use globals, I'd advise before to check again if it is not possible to fix the code to allow calling the functions with more parameters, to avoid a global state (which then becomes a nightmare when debugging).